# How to load a file into memory without decompression? (HDF5)

Tags: python, numpy, compression, hdf5, h5py

Compressing Numpy arrays via `gzip` and `compression_opts=9` reduces filesize 3.38-fold - significant. However, the goal is to load more batches into RAM to accelerate deep learning - which compression doesn't enable, since HDF5-s are *decompressed* upon load.

This said, is it possible to load HDF5 files *without decompression* - to be decompressed *later*, on per-need basis? e.g.

```
hdf5_compressed = h5py.load_without_decompression(filepath)
# do stuff
batch = do_decompression(hdf5_compressed)
```

Comment: Open and read it into an `io.BytesIO` object? http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/file.html#python-file-like-objects

Comment: You can open a `h5py.File`, and access a group and dataset, eg.  `d = f['group/myset']` without loading anything into memory.  But `arr = d[:]` creates are regular numpy array with data loaded from `d`.  There's no such thing as a compressed or latent numpy array.